# trouble pulling html data

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I am attempting to use pandas to scrape a very simple html table from a website.  My code works fine on other sites, but not on the site of interest. It gives me "ValueError: No text parsed from document".  Are there any common situations that prevent this?

I've also tried using requests, but the text property shows up empty as well.

```
urllogin = 'http://website.html'
values = {'user': 'id',
          'password': 'pass'}
r = requests.post(urllogin, data=values)
url = 'http://wesbite/table'
tables = pd.read_html('url')
```

**EDIT**

This returns nothing as well.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: please provide a small __reproducible__ HTML file/contents.

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.